# Why does the C# RegexOptions.Compiled makes the match slower?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, performance

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string RegXPattern = @"/api/(?<controller>\w+)/(?<action>\w+)/?$";
    var regex = new Regex(RegXPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    const string InputToMatch = "/api/person/load";

    regex.IsMatch(InputToMatch); // Warmup

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        var match = regex.IsMatch(InputToMatch);
    }
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Running the above on my machine under *Releae*, finishes in around **18** seconds and removing the `RegexOptions.Compiled` makes it run in **13** seconds.

My understanding was that including this flag would make the match faster but in my example it is resulting in *~30%* lower performance.

What am I missing here?

Comment: testing `IsMatch` and capturing groups is somehow contradictory

Comment: It's not, I am only executing the `regex.Match` to get the named groups when I know there is a match (later in the code) otherwise I would be causing unnecessary `GC` pressure for those unsuccessful matches :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the compiled Regex version does a char by char comparison with the current culture of the form

```
if .... char.ToLower(runtext[index2], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) == 'c' ....
```

where for each character the thread static CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is retrieved.

This shows up in the profiler as CPU consumer:

[image]

I have [filed an issue for .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32764) and [fixed it with a PR](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/32899).
If you need that merged back to the regular .NET Framework you should file an issue at github to request a backport. 
The issue shows up for all compiled Regex which have set

- RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled
- RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled
- RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
  RegexOptions.Compiled

The seemingly strange option *RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled* is in fact necessary if you create a regular expression on a thread with a specific locale which has special casing or number separators. The Regex match expression will be specifically created according to your current locale. If you want a locale independant Regex then you need to use RegexOptions.CultureInvariant.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` that is causing the slow down here. These are my timings for comparison:

```
Compiled     11s
Not compiled 10s
```

Using the inline modifier `(?i)` in the regex gives these results:

```
Compiled     10s
Not compiled 9s
```

Not including the case comparison in the regex (by using `/API/(?<controller>\w+)/(?<action>\w+)/?$` as the pattern, and `.ToUpper()` on the input so that the same number of matches are done):

```
Compiled     6s
Not compiled 8s
```

Taking this one step further (as suggested by Antonín) and using the case-insensitive pattern `/[aA][pP][iI]/(?<controller>\w+)/(?<action>\w+)/?$` gives:

```
Compiled     5s
Not compiled 8s
```

From this, the fastest of them all is using `RegexOptions.Compiled`, but dealing with the casing of the `/api/` prefix using pattern matching in the regex.

To verify these results, I've also ran them using a set of randomised (but still matching) inputs. Here are the results:

```
IgnoreCase | Compiled                13s
IgnoreCase                           11s
(?i) plus Compiled                   13s
(?i)                                 11s
Compiled plus external case handling 9s
External case handling               12s
Case handling in regex plus Compiled 8s
Case handling in regex               11s
```

As to *why* this is slower, [this blog post](https://siderite.blogspot.com/2012/05/on-regexoptionsignorecase-performance.html) discusses a possible reason.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. I am not able to use `.ToUpper` or `.ToLower` due to the `GC` pressure they introduce.

Comment: In that case, you should profile the real code with real inputs when both using and not using `RegexOptions.Compiled` and see which is better for your situation. I'd also make sure that you are micro-optimising a situation that isn't likely to ever be a bottleneck.

Comment: What about @"/[aA][pP][iI]/(?<controller>\w+)/(?<action>\w+)/?$" ?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek That's great! it reduced the time by half! I even tried with longer words/segments and much faster. Post that as an answer and I will it mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: I am glad I helped, but adrianbanks did the hard work here, so I would keep it here. Maybe if he could add this variant to the benchmarks it would be great.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek I've updated my answer with your suggestion, and done the timings for all of them again.

Answer (score 0):

According [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045(v=vs.110).aspx) best practices,

> We recommend that you use interpreted regular expressions when you call regular expression methods with a specific regular expression relatively infrequently. You should use compiled regular expressions when you call regular expression methods with a specific regular expression relatively frequently. The exact threshold at which the slower execution speeds of interpreted regular expressions outweigh gains from their reduced startup time, or the threshold at which the slower startup times of compiled regular expressions outweigh gains from their faster execution speeds, is difficult to determine. It depends on a variety of factors, including the complexity of the regular expression and the specific data that it processes. To determine whether interpreted or compiled regular expressions offer the best performance for your particular application scenario, you can use the Stopwatch class to compare their execution times.

Moreover you have two option supplied to Regex `IgnoreCase` and `Compiled`. If you remove the `IgnoreCase` then `Compiled` option will give you better performance. Also the `Compiled` option is usually  preferred when declaring your `Regex` expressions globally so that they can be compiled at startup.

Comment: I did try the `(?!)` over the the `IgnoreCase` flag before posting the question as it did not make any difference. Declaring the `regex` as static or instance also does not make any difference,

Comment: I just observed it was my machine which was giving great results but it varied on other one which is why I removed the code sample. The option is `(?i)` not `(?!)`.

Comment: I think you meant to say the correct option is `(?!)` not `(?!):` which you originally posted :-)

Comment: Yup `:` doesn't work in .Net but it's `i` the alphabet not `!` :)

Comment: Yes, typo on my side.